# Memcache stats hide (page)

Tags: php, mysql, memcached, php-5.5

I am trying to use memcache at my host but when I include memcache at my php code, a page with the memcache stats shows up at my html and mess up my page.

I just insert

```
include('memcache.php');
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect to cache.your_server.com");
```

on my code and memcache stats page showed up.

Any thoughts how to disable it's appearance?

Comment: You have tried what? Apart from coming straight to SO after minimal/no effort to resolve the problem yourself?

Comment: Who said that? I searched up and down the memcache.php I could only comment its html, but when I did that my page didn't appear at all. I am googling the last hour about this problem and there is not even a clue where to disable it. :/

Comment: What code are you using on this page that show the memcache stats? please show it

Comment: I just insert include('memcache.php');
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or  die ("Could not connect to cache.your_server.com"); on my code and memcache stats page showed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memcache.php` file that you're including *is* the stats page. It's not intended to be included.

Comment: So simple I didn't even imagine it. Dumb me.